# Is there any way to get resquest type and response type by service type?

Tags: grpc

assume I have a gRPC service and a rpc method, defined by protobuf:

```
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}
```

and I want to implement an class, received a template type named `RpcMethod`, can I get the resquest type and the response type specificed by RpcMethod type ?

for example:

```cpp
template<typename RpcMethod>
class RpcCallData {
public:
    using RequestType = RpcMethod::RequestType;
    using ResponseType = RpcMethod::ResponseType;
private:
    RequestType request;
    ResponseType response;
};

RpcCallData<Greeter> data;
```

and then, I can deduce the type of `request` and `response` which is `HelloRequest` and `HelloReply`, respectively。

Comment: First thing to note here is that `Greeter` your service, not an RPC Method. SayHello is your RPC endpoint. Then after, looking a little bit at the generated code having the type like you want doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Thank you，I forget change the template parameter for RpcCallData, it should be `SayHello`.  I think it's possible adding some type traits for rpc method class when `protoc ` doing codegen, but I cannot find some relate information in the code.